# Issues with Meteor JS and IE8

Tags: javascript, meteor, internet-explorer-8

I keep getting the below error in the IE8 console, causing the page to not render:

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
Timestamp: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 17:58:51 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 66
Char: 1093
Code: 0


Message: 'Package.service-configuration.ServiceConfiguration' is null or not an object
Line: 84
Char: 1628
Code: 0
```

Here's a list of the packages my project is using:

```
accounts-base 1.2.0

accounts-password 1.1.1

aldeed:auto form 5.3.0* 

aldeed:collection2 2.3.3*

fabienb4:autoform-semantic-ui 0.4.0*

forwarder:autoform-wizard 0.7.0

forwarder:autoform-wizard-iron-router 0.1.1* 

http 1.1.0

iron:router 1.0.9

jeremy:autoform-selectize 0.1.1

kenken:meteor-counters 1.2.0*

meteor-platform 1.2.2

meteorhacks:npm 1.3.0*

momentjs:moment 2.10.3*

multiply:iron-router-progress 1.0.1

npm-container 1.0.0+

semantic:ui-css 1.12.3*

yasinuslu:blaze-meta 0.3.1*
```

In terms of config, I'm not doing anything fancy...just a MongoDB backend running on Phusion Passenger/NGINX.

Comment: With what configuration, what packages, what code?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, as per this thread:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3506

Add the following package:

```
meteor add service-configuration
```

This causes (at least part of) the page to render. I am getting additional JavaScript errors, but they are related to the packages I'm using.